# How to get work profile container working on a rooted device

Tags: root-access, 8.0-oreo, magisk, samsung-knox, work-profiles

I want to use work profile container with shelter on a rooted device
I have pached most of samsung knox by using [smali patcher](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/module-smali-patcher-7-4.3680053/) magisk module and to use shealth changing `build.prop` entry from `ro.config.tima=1` to `ro.config.tima=0`
This is all the progress that I have made so how so I get work profile container to work
It's displaying

> The security policy prevents the creation of a managed device because a custom OS is or has been installed on this device